# Stream music from another music app in my application

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media

I have an android app that works in all other aspects except it doesn't have background music, but I don't have custom music.

I would also like users to play their own songs that they like as background music.

I have been trying for a week to figure out how to do this, and have come to the conclusion that I might as well use a different app that ALREADY has their music.

Now I don't know how to do this...

So, how would I go about using a different app (Google Music, Spotify, etc.) that that the user has installed, to play background music that they bought and own in my app?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear for me what you want to achieve.

**Intents:**

*You could use Intents to start an other app and play music.*

- **Pro:** easy to implement
- **Con:** user will left your app and has to navigate back.

**SDKs**

Spotify has a [free SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/)

- **Pro:** you have full control, your app can be a full spotify music player
- **Con:** only Spotify premium, a lot of effort to implement

**Radio:**

You could use a free mediaplayer class and implement WebRadio
 - **Pro:** full control
 - **Con:** only radio, no specific music

Comment: Thank you. Is there no other way though? I already have an intent system set up but it only can play ringtones... It picks the ringtone and loops it in the background using a media player. I just want to do this using music not ringtones.